Ideas for high school research project related to probability
I am a yr11 high school student under the IB curriculum looking to write my extended essay on Mathematics. I have my interest set on probability and generating functions. After doing some research, I found that probability generating functions can solve many probablems like random walk and randomly stopped sum.
I am currently working through a book called Grinstead and Snell's Introduction to Probability to learn the background knowledge. I know very little about the field, so I am trying my best to grasp what I am getting myself into. I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right path!

Peter, are you looking for help with mathematics, or help with the computer algebra system called Mathematica? This questions/answers site is for the latter, which is why you are receiving answers with Mathematica code. Please let us know, so this question can be moved to the correct Q/A site.

Oh no, I was meant seek help for mathematics. I am so sorry for the mistake. My apologies.

Here's a suggestion. The code below calculates volatility and drift from a stock price history, then runs random walks and overlays probability confidence bounds. Plenty to find out about.
The calculations are from the first 2 chapters of Computational Financial Mathematics using Mathematica.
ge = Take[If[$VersionNumber < 12,
   FinancialData["GE", "Feb. 1, 2024"],

   (* reformat input data *)
   {Take[DateList[#1], 3], QuantityMagnitude[#2]} & @@@ 
    Normal[FinancialData["GE", "Feb. 1, 2024"]],
   162 (* up to today *)]];

Print[DateListPlot[ge, Joined -> True,
   PlotLabel -> "GE stock price since " <> DateString[ge[[1, 1]],
      {"Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}],
   FrameLabel -> {None, Style["$", Large]}, RotateLabel -> False]];

(* Convert timescales to years since 01 Jan 2000 *)
{dates, prices} = Transpose[ge];
YearLength = 1/100 AbsoluteTime[{2000, 1, 1}];
YearClock[y_] := 
  N[(AbsoluteTime[y] - AbsoluteTime[{2000, 1, 1}])/YearLength];
times = YearClock /@ dates;
PriceList = Transpose[{times, prices}];

Print[ListLinePlot[PriceList,
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Timescale converted to years since " <> DateString[{2000, 1, 1},
      {"Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}]]];

(* Calculate volatility *)
Av[List_] := Plus @@ Flatten[List]/Length[Flatten[List]];
Σ[PriceList_] := Module[{dS, S, dt},
   dS = Drop[prices, 1] - Drop[prices, -1];
   S = Drop[prices, -1];
   dt = Drop[times, 1] - Drop[times, -1];
   Sqrt[Av[dS^2/(S^2 dt)]]];
σ = Σ[PriceList];

(* Estimate appreciation *)
AEst[PriceList_] := Module[{σ, T},
   σ = Σ[PriceList];
   T = Last[times] - First[times];
   σ^2/2 + (Log[Last[prices]] - Log[First[prices]])/T];
a = AEst[PriceList];

(* Solve stochastic differential equation *)
SDESolver[f_, σ_, y0_, t0_, t1_, K_] := Module[{dt, dB, G},
   dt = N[(t1 - t0)/K];
   dB = Table[Random[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[dt]]], {K}];
   G[{t_, y_}, db_] := {t + dt, y + f[t, y] dt + σ[t, y] db};
   FoldList[G, {t0, y0}, dB]];

With[{L = 100, K = 1000},
  data = Table[
    SDESolver[a #2 &, σ #2 &,
     First[prices], First[times], Last[times], K], {L}]];

Print[Show[ListLinePlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {times[[{1, -1}]], {0, 500}},
    AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
   ListLinePlot[PriceList, PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thick}]]];

T = Last[times] - First[times];
Subscript[y, 0] = First[prices];
Z[a_, σ_, b_, t_] = 
  Subscript[y, 0] E^((a - σ^2/2) t + b σ Sqrt[t]);
Pix2 = Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[Z[a, σ, b, t], {b, -3, 3}]], {t, 0, T}];
Pix3 = Plot[Subscript[y, 0] E^(a t), {t, 0, T}];

P2linepos = Position[Pix2, Line];
P2lines = First /@ Extract[Pix2, Most /@ P2linepos];
newP2lines = P2lines /. {t_, s_} :> {t + First[times], s};

P3linepos = Position[Pix3, Line];
P3lines = First /@ Extract[Pix3, Most /@ P3linepos];
newP3lines = P3lines /. {t_, s_} :> {t + First[times], s};

Print[cbm = Show[ListLinePlot[newP2lines,
     PlotStyle -> {Orange, Orange, Orange, {Dashed, Yellow},
       Orange, Orange, Orange},
     PlotRange -> {times[[{1, -1}]], {0, 500}},
     AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
    ListLinePlot[newP3lines,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]], Background -> Gray]];

Print[Show[ListLinePlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {times[[{1, -1}]], {0, 500}},
    AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
   Most@cbm, ListLinePlot[PriceList,
    PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thick}], Pix3, ImageSize -> 600]];

futuretimes = (times - First@times) + Last@times;

With[{L = 100, K = 1000},
  data = Table[
    SDESolver[a #2 &, σ #2 &,
     Last[prices], First[futuretimes], Last[futuretimes], K], {L}]];

Print[Show[ListLinePlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {{First@times, Last@futuretimes}, {0, 600}},
    AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
   ListLinePlot[PriceList, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]];

(* Display confidence bounds, median (dashed yellow), and mean (red) *)

T = Last[futuretimes] - First[futuretimes];
Subscript[y, 0] = Last[prices];
Z[a_, σ_, b_, t_] = 
  Subscript[y, 0] E^((a - σ^2/2) t + b σ Sqrt[t]);
Pix2 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[Z[a, σ, b, t], {b, -3, 3}]],
  {t, 0, T}]; Pix3 = Plot[Subscript[y, 0] E^(a t), {t, 0, T}];

P2linepos = Position[Pix2, Line];
P2lines = First /@ Extract[Pix2, Most /@ P2linepos];
newP2lines = P2lines /. {t_, s_} :> {t + First[futuretimes], s};

P3linepos = Position[Pix3, Line];
P3lines = First /@ Extract[Pix3, Most /@ P3linepos];
newP3lines = P3lines /. {t_, s_} :> {t + First[futuretimes], s};

Print[cbm = Show[ListLinePlot[newP2lines,
     PlotStyle -> {Orange, Orange, Orange, {Dashed, Yellow},
       Orange, Orange, Orange},
     PlotRange -> {{First@times, Last@futuretimes}, {0, 700}},
     AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
    ListLinePlot[newP3lines,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]], Background -> Gray]];

Print[Show[ListLinePlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {{First@times, Last@futuretimes}, {0, 700}},
    AxesOrigin -> {First@times, 0}],
   Most@cbm, ListLinePlot[PriceList,
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], Pix3, ImageSize -> 600]];



@Moo Thanks for pointing that out. I put it together in version 11.2 and have now added a reformat for the input data based on version 13.2.

It works perfectly now!
